# Photoswipe.js detect event when the pswp gallery is closed

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

When closing Photoswipe, [it has some leftover elements on the DOM that breaks it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991073/photoswipe-does-not-close-properly-in-this-implementation-with-slick-carousel), so I want to use jQuery to reset it every time it's closed. How can I get the event when Photoswipe closed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PhotoSwipe](https://photoswipe.com/documentation/api.html) events.

```js
// Event fire when Gallery starts closing
pswp.listen('close', function() { 
    // code here
});

// Even trigers when Gallery unbinds events
// (triggers before closing animation)
pswp.listen('unbindEvents', function() {
    // code here
});

// Event fires when only after the gallery is closed and closing animation finished.
pswp.listen('destroy', function() {
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/api.html):

```
// After gallery is closed and closing animation finished.
// Clean up your stuff here.
pswp.listen('destroy', function() { });
```